# Loop through all children of an div

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, parent, children

i'm busy with an page which will load some information from an database, but to do this I first have to declare some stuff. But I need to get access to all the elements inside an html object. So if my HTML code is like this:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="parent1">
            <div class="child1ofparent1"></div>
            <div class="child2ofparent1"></div>
            <div class="child3ofparent1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="parent2">
            <div class="child1ofparent2"></div>
            <div class="child2ofparent2"></div>
            <div class="child3ofparent2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="parent3">
            <div class="child1ofparent3"></div>
            <div class="child2ofparent3"></div>
            <div class="child3ofparent3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to loop through all childrens just by calling `$(".container");`

The way i'm doing it now is just by looping through everything hardcoded, but since the application will be used by my school some things need to be more flexible.

I already tried this:

```js
$(".container > *").each(function(i, element) {
       console.log(element);
    });
```

But this only returns the first children (.parent1, .parent2, .parent3).

Comment: Recursion is your friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) - `".container > *"`. Use the [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) instead - `".container *"`.

```js
$(".container *").each(function(i, element) {
  console.log(element);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent1">
    <div class="child1ofparent1"></div>
    <div class="child2ofparent1"></div>
    <div class="child3ofparent1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent2">
    <div class="child1ofparent2"></div>
    <div class="child2ofparent2"></div>
    <div class="child3ofparent2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent3">
    <div class="child1ofparent3"></div>
    <div class="child2ofparent3"></div>
    <div class="child3ofparent3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers are correct, the universal selector (`*`) should be discouraged if possible due to the fact that it matches any element, not just the one's you are looking for which, depending on your *DOM* tree, may have a significant impact on your performance. You may be able to use an attribute selector such as the one shown below:

```js
$(function () {

  var $output = $('#output');

  $('.container [class^="child"]').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('<li />', { text: $this.prop('nodeName') + " w/ class " + $this.attr('class') }).appendTo($output);
  });

});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16;
}
#output {
  list-style-type: square;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div class="parent1">
            <div class="child1ofparent1"></div>
            <div class="child2ofparent1"></div>
            <div class="child3ofparent1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="parent2">
            <div class="child1ofparent2"></div>
            <div class="child2ofparent2"></div>
            <div class="child3ofparent2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="parent3">
            <div class="child1ofparent3"></div>
            <div class="child2ofparent3"></div>
            <div class="child3ofparent3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h1>Selected Elements:</h1>
    <ul id="output"></ul>
```

**Reference:** [Attribute Starts With Selector `[name^=”value”]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

This will return all children that have `.container` as an ancestor

```js
    $("*", ".container").each(function(i, element) {
       console.log(element);
    });
```

Comment: Not really, this selector will essentially select every single element of the page; think of the comma (`,`) as an `or` operator.

Comment: This is an `or` selection which will return all of the elements on the page. Not quite what the OP is looking for...

Comment: $("a, b") is a or b. $("a", "b") is for all b in a

Answer (score 0):

You were close. `".container > *"` means to look for children only, not all descendants.

Remove the `>` symbol to loop over descendants.

```js
$(".container *").each(function(i, element) {
  console.log(element.classList[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div class="parent1">
            <div class="child1ofparent1"></div>
            <div class="child2ofparent1"></div>
            <div class="child3ofparent1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="parent2">
            <div class="child1ofparent2"></div>
            <div class="child2ofparent2"></div>
            <div class="child3ofparent2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="parent3">
            <div class="child1ofparent3"></div>
            <div class="child2ofparent3"></div>
            <div class="child3ofparent3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I was wondering the same thing _Scott_. This is the same as the accepted answer. Can't see anything wrong with it. +1

Answer (score 0):

My own suggestion. Use the div to determine the level of nesting you want.

For first parent use

```js
$(".container > div").each(function(i, element) {
  console.log(element);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent1">
    <div class="child1ofparent1"></div>
    <div class="child2ofparent1"></div>
    <div class="child3ofparent1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent2">
    <div class="child1ofparent2"></div>
    <div class="child2ofparent2"></div>
    <div class="child3ofparent2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent3">
    <div class="child1ofparent3"></div>
    <div class="child2ofparent3"></div>
    <div class="child3ofparent3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For only children with parent use

```js
$(".container div div").each(function(i, element) {
  console.log(element);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent1">
    <div class="child1ofparent1"></div>
    <div class="child2ofparent1"></div>
    <div class="child3ofparent1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent2">
    <div class="child1ofparent2"></div>
    <div class="child2ofparent2"></div>
    <div class="child3ofparent2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent3">
    <div class="child1ofparent3"></div>
    <div class="child2ofparent3"></div>
    <div class="child3ofparent3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For all children: parent and child use

```js
$(".container div").each(function(i, element) {
  console.log(element);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent1">
    <div class="child1ofparent1"></div>
    <div class="child2ofparent1"></div>
    <div class="child3ofparent1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent2">
    <div class="child1ofparent2"></div>
    <div class="child2ofparent2"></div>
    <div class="child3ofparent2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent3">
    <div class="child1ofparent3"></div>
    <div class="child2ofparent3"></div>
    <div class="child3ofparent3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```